# ExtTextOut not displaying subscript characters

Tags: winapi, unicode, fonts, drawtext

I'm attempting to render the following text using the [`ExtTextOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162713%28VS.85%29.aspx) function with the `Courier New` font:

```
C₁C₂C²C³
```

The superscript characters show up fine, but the subscript characters show up as blocks. If I use the [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498%28VS.85%29.aspx) function, then the subscript characters show up fine.

I was under the impression that [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498%28VS.85%29.aspx) internally calls [`ExtTextOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162713%28VS.85%29.aspx). Am I mistaken or does [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498%28VS.85%29.aspx) perform some extra processing of the string to allow subscript characters to show up?

Is there anything I can do to get [`ExtTextOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162713%28VS.85%29.aspx) to display the subscript characters using the `Courier New` font?

My code for using [`ExtTextOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162713%28VS.85%29.aspx) looks like this:

```
ExtTextOutW(hdc,x,y,0,0,szText,wcslen(szText),0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Hans noted in a comment, DrawText() is nowadays implemented using font linking, but it would appear that ExtTextOut() is not.

If you really want this to work reliably, you'll probably have to do font linking yourself. Some code of mine that solves a similar problem: [TextOutput C++ class](https://github.com/DavidKinder/Libraries/blob/1882de4e9bd7321f76a22b1aab92d3229de60ca1/mfc/TextOutput.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

If you get rectangles instead of glyphs then the problem is the font you are using.  It doesn't have the necessary glyph.  Common on XP for example, I don't have it installed anymore to check.  Use the Windows charmap.exe applet to find a suitable font.  The subscript 2 is Unicode codepoint '\x2082'.

Comment: I am aware of this. Selecting a different (e.g. Segoe UI) will display the subscript characters. However, why does the DrawText function display the subscript characters, even when using the Courier New font? Does the DrawText function perform some extra font substitutions?

Comment: That API function dates from the stone age, it might not implement the font linking feature.  Not sure, I haven't used it in ages.  Backgrounder is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134.aspx